# Как сохранить результат выполнения playbook в лог файл

Tags: ansible

Есть playbook который в свою очередь запускает роль з тасками. Как сохранить результат выполнения или не выполнения (stdout) playbook (всех задач) в лог файл? Метод настройки ansible.cfg log_path не подходит так как там логи не структурированы по каждому плейбуку, а у меня их запускаеться несколько. Тоесть схема примерно такая - запускаеться плейбук - после выполнения на роб. столе сохраняеться файла "название playbook".log. И так для каждого.
   Большое спасибо за дельные советы.

Comment: Ну если мы не ограничиваемся чистым ансиблом и жинжа, то можно попробовать `tee`.